# Running a NodeJS cron from cron-job.org

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, server-side, serverside-javascript

I am trying to run a NodeJS cron at a set interval using [cron-job.org](https://cron-job.org/en/), but they don't have any documentation about how to actually run the script.

Basically the service visits a URL that you provide at a set interval, but I am specifically confused about what kind of code I can put on the endpoint (specifically what type of code will actually run). Can someone provide an example of what I would put at the endpoint URL?

Comment: A bit outside the scope of your question, but why don't you just use a package like [`node-cron`](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something really simple using either the HTTP module in Node.js or the popular Express module. Using express you can do something really simple like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get("/test", function(req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify({ status: 'OK', timeStamp: new Date().toISOString() }));
});

console.log('Express listening.. on 3000');
app.listen(3000);
```

You can really run anything you like in the /test endpoint, though when it's being called from cron-job.org they'll probably stop if you keep throwing back 400 errors at them or the script takes really long to execute.

You'd call this using the url

```
http://yourdomain:3000/test
```

And of course you might well want to change the port number and path!

Answer (score 0):

cron-job.org only allows you to call an endpoint at a set time interval.

If you want to have some code run at a set interval without worrying about HTTP server, deploying, etc... Check out services like [chunk.run](https://chunk.run)

Here's an example code:
https://chunk.run/c/scheduled-run-example

Then you can just select the trigger "Scheduled" like so:

[image: scheduled trigger chunk run]